# Setup A Program to Run At Startup As A Specified User On Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, sudo

I have a server running `Debian 12` that does not have `root` access enabled as recommended by many. I do have an another user `admin` privileged account on the server.

I have a program that does not come with a service bundled with it.

I have created user `unprivileged` on the server that has limited access to the filesystem and no `sudo`.

I have an application that `unprivileged` owns I would like to run as `unprivileged` at startup.

I have for now manually logged in as `admin` and ran `screen` and then `sudo su unprivileged` to first change user and then inside the screen ran `./program` and after `Ctrl+A-D` to detach from the screen to leave it running in the background.

I doubt if it is safe to run applications this way as it seems like a way for a potential attacker to escape to the more privileged shell. It does concern me as it does seem like a hack.

How can I setup my system so I can run `./program` at startup as my low privileged `unprivileged` in the background? Are there any other "obvious" setup I should be aware of in this situation?

Comment: Use systemd service type=simple or type=exec. There are pleeeenty of manuals in the Internet; what you've tried so far and what went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## crontab

Only if you need to interact with the program similarly than you do now, this solution could work for you. You could put the program & the screen in the `crontab` of the user `unprivileged`, e.g.,

1. Run `sudo su -c 'crontab -e' unprivileged`
2. Add a line:

   ```
   @reboot sleep 60 && /usr/bin/screen -d -m /home/unprivileged/program
   ```

   Where,

   - `@reboot` runs the command at the boot
   - `sleep 60 &&` adds a delay of `60` seconds before running the program
   - `/usr/bin/screen` puths the program inside a `screen` terminal multiplexer
   - `-d -m` starts the screen in detached mode (useful for system startup scripts)
   - `/home/unprivileged/program` is the path for the actual program

This way both the `screen` & the `./program` are run as the user, and you can interact with the program by.

```
$ sudo su - unprivileged
$ screen -r
```

## SystemD service

If the program can be run in the background without user interaction, this is the best option. The program will run as a service. The stdout & stderr will be sent to the SystemD journal.

1. Place a unit file to `/etc/systemd/system/unprivileged-program.service`, e.g.,

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Service for running program as user unpriviged

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   User=unprivileged
   WorkingDirectory=/home/unprivileged
   ExecStart=/home/unprivileged/program
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
2. Reload the service files: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Start your new service: `sudo systemctl start unprivileged-program.service`
4. Check the program is running correctly, e.g., with

   - `sudo systemctl status unprivileged-program.service`
   - `sudo journalctl -u unprivileged-program`
5. Enable the service to be started on every boot:
   `sudo systemctl enable unprivileged-program.service`